# Postman post parameter returning null

Tags: php, postman

I am tring to learn how to use postman with the following basic php script:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];

$j = array('name' =>$name);
echo json_encode($j);
?>
```

In the chrome postman application, I enter the params:

Key: test
Value: test

but this returns {"name":null}

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong please?

[image]

Comment: your key should be `name`, not `test`

Comment: THis still returns {"name":null}

Comment: You have to send it as a `POST` request too.

Comment: yes, still doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: Did you add the params in the `Body` tab of Postman? Or did you click the `Params` button beside the `Send` button?

Comment: I clicked the Params button bedide the send button

Comment: You have to put it in the Body tab on the right of Authorization. The params tab is for `GET` params.

Comment: Actually, that got it, thank you Chin

Answer (score 1):

> X-www-form-urluncoded

this solved my problem ,don't not use form-data